# mysql insert with multiple select statement

Tags: mysql

I want to insert data to a table with values coming from 3 different tables

table class_teachers_section
    class_ref  teachers_ref section_ref
        2             3       2 
        1             6       2

table class
     id    name    hours
     1      pe        3

table teachers
     id    first_name   last_name
      1       Lenovo       Lenovo

table section
      id     name
       1      grade 4

class_teachers_section is a intermediary table  ... here is my statement

```
INSERT INTO class_teachers_section(class_ref, teachers_ref, section_ref)
    values (
        (class_ref, (select class.id as class_ref from class where class.name = 'pe')),
        (teachers_ref, (select teachers.id as teachers_ref from teachers where
                    teachers.last_name = 'lenevo')),
        (section_ref, (select section.id as section_ref from section where section.name =
                   'grade 4'))
    )
```

## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

do you guys have any idea how to resolve this? thanks

tried this  ..

```
INSERT INTO class_teachers_section(class_ref, teachers_ref, section_ref)
    values( (select class.id as class_ref from class where class.name = 'pe'),
           (select teachers.id as teachers_ref from teachers where teachers.last_name = 'lenevo'),
           (select section.id as section_ref from section where section.name = 'grade 4'))
```

teachers_ref can not be null error

Comment: You should omit the values clause and use the [INSERT ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) syntax.

Comment: tried it but it didn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is rather unusual.  You have three columns in the `insert` list but have six elements in the `values` list.  Three of them appear to be column names.

That is not how `select` works.  Instead, the columns correspond by position.

In your case, though, you should use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO class_teachers_section(class_ref, teachers_ref, section_ref)
    select (select class.id as class_ref from class where class.name = 'pe'),
           (select teachers.id as teachers_ref from teachers where teachers.last_name = 'lenevo'),
           (select section.id as section_ref from section where section.name = 'grade 4');
```

Comment: @RonaldManlapao . . . I can see why it might have missed `section_ref` -- the parentheses were unbalanced.  It will insert `NULL` if subqueries do not find any rows.